# My System Unit got di di sound, not sure where is it from, it is happen when I do video rendering

Tags: audio

My System Unit got "di di" sound, not sure where is it from, it is happen when I do video rendering. The PC still working, no restart, but the sound keep continue until it finished rendering.

This is the video link

http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=21boyep&s=8#.VCJ-IfmSySo

Comment: Your cpu/video card is overheating

Comment: search for a cpu temperature monitor.

Comment: so the sound is came from video/cpu? I suspect the sound is from PSU, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sound is come from Graphic Card Warning. It is overheat, and it is totally dead....